# How do I build a precise formation of nested divs from a recursive query?

Tags: php, html

I have a somewhat complex recursive postgresql query that pulls in something (I have simplified it for the purposes of this question) like this:

```
id  depth   path        has_children

1   1       1           true
2   2       1.2         true
3   3       1.2.3       true
4   4       1.2.3.4     true
5   5       1.2.3.4.5   false
6   1       6           true
7   2       6.7         true
8   3       6.7.8       false
9   1       9           false
10  1       10          true
11  2       10.11       false
```

This is the result as fetched (for those wondering why I parsed some arrays as objects it is because the rows are fetched as objects and I am just duplicating the result):

```
$tree = array
(
    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 1,
        "depth" => 1,
        "path" => "1",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 2,
        "depth" => 2,
        "path" => "1.2",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 3,
        "depth" => 3,
        "path" => "1.2.3",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 4,
        "depth" => 4,
        "path" => "1.2.3.4",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 5,
        "depth" => 5,
        "path" => "1.2.3.4.5",
        "has_children" => false
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 6,
        "depth" => 1,
        "path" => "6",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 7,
        "depth" => 2,
        "path" => "6.7",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 8,
        "depth" => 3,
        "path" => "6.7.8",
        "has_children" => false
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 9,
        "depth" => 1,
        "path" => "9",
        "has_children" => false
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 10,
        "depth" => 1,
        "path" => "10",
        "has_children" => true
    ),

    (object) array
    (
        "id" => 11,
        "depth" => 2,
        "path" => "10.11",
        "has_children" => false
    )
);
```

I want to turn the result into this (with the given class names):

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>1.2</p>
            </div>

            <div class="baz">
                <div class="qux">
                    <p>1.2.3</p>
                </div>

                <div class="baz">
                    <div class="qux">
                        <p>1.2.3.4</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="baz">
                        <div class="qux">
                            <p>1.2.3.4.5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>

        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>6.7</p>
            </div>

            <div class="baz">
                <div class="qux">
                    <p>6.7.8</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>9</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>10</p>
        </div>

        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>10.11</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I have gone and confused myself after looking at too many examples involving `ul` and `li`. Tweaking such examples for my uses have failed as nested `ul`s and `li`s are different than nested `div`s.

I'd like a clean solution that uses a `foreach` (preferably) or `while` loop (a recursive function is not necessary). I also do not wish to recreate the result as an multidimensional array.

Comment: you want to display the data or the html code?

Comment: @PsyCoder: I want to build the html code in the given format.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid If you could provide an example of the data, perhaps in a nested array, it would be much easier to help with.

Comment: Just keep track of the current `path` length (i.e. depth) and compare it with the length from the new row, then open and close `<div>`s appropriately.

Comment: @JMack: I edited my answer to provide the data.

Comment: @mu is too short: At this point I'm just moving code around and playing with values. I have no idea what's going on anymore. Which is why I'm here asking for help.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid Is there some reason that you are casting your arrays as objects?

Comment: @JMack: The query returns an object. I was just duplicating the behavior.

Comment: Why is this tagged with postgresql? It seems you are looking for a PHP/HTML solution only.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My apologies, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the prettiest code, but it outputs exactly as you specified:

```
<div id="foo">
<?php

$openingElement = true;
$divsOpened = 0;
$indent = 1;

foreach ($tree as $row) {
    if ($openingElement === true) {
        print str_repeat(' ', $indent * 4) . '<div class="bar">' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        print str_repeat(' ', $indent * 4) . '<div class="baz">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $indent++;
    $divsOpened++;

    print str_repeat(' ', $indent * 4) . '<div class="qux">' . PHP_EOL;
    $indent++;
    print str_repeat(' ', $indent * 4) . '<p>' . $row->path . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
    $indent--;
    print str_repeat(' ', $indent * 4) . '</div>' . PHP_EOL;

    if ($row->has_children) {
        $openingElement = false;
        print PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        for ($i = $divsOpened; $i > 0; $i--) {
            print str_repeat(' ', $i * 4) . '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
            $indent--;
            $divsOpened--;
        }
        $openingElement = true;
    }
}

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Very close. From what I can see the bar class is used once when it should be used four times.

Comment: I updated the code. It was missing the "$openingElement = true;" line. Now it's printing the classes as it should.

Comment: After trying to implement JMack's code I remembered why I didn't want to deal with a recursive function. I prettied up this code instead and it worked nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the db data into an array which you can loop through and using both depth and has_children, pass the data to a new multi-dimensional array as:

```
array(
    '1' => array(
        '1.2' => array(
            '1.2.3' => array(
                '1.2.3.4' => array('1.2.3.4.5')
            )
        )
    ),
    '6' => array(
        '6.7' => array('6.7.8')
    )
);
```

etc. Then you can loop it and use a foreach to echo each array as a div.

Imagine you have the fetched data from the example table you posted in the form `array('row' => array('key' => 'value', 'etc' => 'more'))`. For each row, you will need to check the `['has_children']` value. If it evaluates as true, you should then get the depth as an integer and use a for loop such as `for ($i=0; $i<$depth; $i++)`, creating an array of arrays as the one written above.

There's several ways to do this, the simplier is to create the arrays recursively, such as
`$array = '1.2.3.4.5'` then `$array = array('1.2.3.4' => $array)`, until you have a multi-dimensional array as the written above.

Having that array, it's as simple as:

```
function display($multiarray) {
    foreach ($multiarray as $name=>$path) {
        if (is_array($path)) {
            // Check if it's the first.
            $class = (strpos('.', $name)) ? 'baz' : 'bar';
            echo "<div class='{$class}'>\n\t";
            echo "<div class='qux'>\n\t<p>{$name}</p>\n</div>\n\n";
            display($path);
            echo "</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='baz'>\n\t";
            echo "<div class='qux'>\n\t<p>{$path}</p>\n</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Made it on the fly, but I hope you get the main idea.

Comment: I understand the idea but I'm working with a flat array. There's no reason for me to go through it again and build a multi-dimensional array when the recursive query provides enough information to do without.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid A recursive function works most naturally with nested data. Joim's answer is elegant. I'm trying to see if I can figure out how to do it with nested data, but it's proving difficult.

Comment: @JMack: The issue I have with with recreating the result as a multi-dimensional array is that the result actually has a lot more columns than what I provided and can return as much as a few hundred rows. Knowing that, it doesn't seem time efficient to recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your data being flat makes it more difficult to write a recursive function. A recursive function works most naturally with nested data. It took a while, but I was able to create a partially recursive solution that works with your flat data.

```
<?php
$tree = array(array("id"=>1,"depth"=>1,"path"=>"1","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>2,"depth"=>2,"path"=>"1.2","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>3,"depth"=>3,"path"=>"1.2.3","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>4,"depth"=>4,"path"=>"1.2.3.4","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>5,"depth"=>5,"path"=>"1.2.3.4.5","has_children"=>false),array("id"=>6,"depth"=>1,"path"=>"6","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>7,"depth"=>2,"path"=>"6.7","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>8,"depth"=>3,"path"=>"6.7.8","has_children"=>false),array("id"=>9,"depth"=>1,"path"=>"9","has_children"=>false),array("id"=>10,"depth"=>1,"path"=>"10","has_children"=>true),array("id"=>11,"depth"=>2,"path"=>"10.11","has_children"=>false));

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

function print_tree(&$tree, $i, $top_level)
{
    $indent = str_repeat('    ', $tree[$i]['depth']);

    echo $indent."<div class=\"".($top_level ? 'bar' : 'baz')."\">\n";
    echo $indent."    <div class=\"qux\">\n";
    echo $indent."        <p>".$tree[$i]['path']."</p>\n";
    echo $indent."    </div>\n";

    if($tree[$i]['has_children'])
    {
        print_tree($tree, $i+1, false);
    }

    echo $indent."</div>\n";
}

echo "<div id=\"foo\">\n";

$count = count($tree);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
{
    if($tree[$i]['depth'] == 1)
    {
        print_tree($tree, $i, true);
    }
}

echo "</div>\n";
?>
```

This will output:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>1.2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="baz">
                <div class="qux">
                    <p>1.2.3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="baz">
                    <div class="qux">
                        <p>1.2.3.4</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="baz">
                        <div class="qux">
                            <p>1.2.3.4.5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>6.7</p>
            </div>
            <div class="baz">
                <div class="qux">
                    <p>6.7.8</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>9</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="qux">
            <p>10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="baz">
            <div class="qux">
                <p>10.11</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The classes I gave for the divs are actually important. I don't see anything here that determine what to name them.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid Can't you add in the class names yourself? I already spent 20 minutes working on the hard part for you. The rest is just cosmetic formatting.

Comment: I appreciate your 20 minutes. Really, I do, since I already spent more than a few days on this with no success. That said, it may be just cosmetic, but I don't understand it and I don't have a problem admitting that. In your code the `div` tag opens repetitively in one place. I don't see how to determine what class goes where.

Comment: I've added in the class names to match the example.

Comment: This works as intended and I now understand the logic I was missing. Thank you and I apologize for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

This shiny piece of **pure SQL** will generate your string exactly:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
          ,(lag(depth) OVER (ORDER BY id) +1) - depth AS end_divs
          ,CASE WHEN depth = 1 THEN 'bar' ELSE 'baz' END AS class
          ,E'\n' || repeat('    ', depth) AS i -- newline + indent
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY id
    )
SELECT '<div id="foo">'
    || string_agg(
          CASE WHEN end_divs > 0 THEN 
             (SELECT string_agg(repeat ('    ', n), E'</div>\n')
              FROM   generate_series (end_divs,0,-1) n)
          ELSE '' END
          || i || '<div class="' || class ||'">'
          || i || '    <div class="qux">'
          || i || '        <p>' || path || '</p>'
          || i || '    </div>'
        , E'\n' ORDER BY id
       )
    || (SELECT E'\n' || string_agg(repeat ('    ', n-1), E'</div>\n')
        FROM   generate_series((SELECT depth+1 FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
                              , 0 , -1) n)
FROM   x;
```

It's not very easy to read, I'll leave documenting the features to you.

Comment: Not sure if you are poking fun at me but that's okay. I laughed and I upvoted you anyway because: (1) you answered my question despite providing a solution I can't use in this scenario (2) your answer might help someone else. Thanks!